# pass parameter inside jQuery Function

Tags: jquery

I want to pass "this" to "success" function i have tried to put "this" keyword as parameter inside brackets of success function..how to pass this key word inside success function? ... but it did not work...may be my english language not good ..sorry for that.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".join").click(
                function () {
                    if ($(this).text() == "join")
                    {
                        var FollowOptions = {};
                        @*FollowOptions.url = "/@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name/Communities/Follow/";*@
                        FollowOptions.url = "/@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name/Groups/Join/";
                        FollowOptions.data = { id: $(this).attr("name") };
                        FollowOptions.success = function (this) {
                            $(this).prop("text", "leave");
                            $(this).removeClass("btn btn-info");
                            $(this).addClass("btn btn-danger");

                        };
              $.ajax(FollowOptions);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var FollowOptions = {};
                        FollowOptions.url = "/@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name/Groups/UnJoin/";
                        FollowOptions.data = { id: $(this).attr("name") };
                        FollowOptions.success = function (this) {
                            $(this).prop("text", "join");
                            $(this).removeClass("btn btn-danger");
                            $(this).addClass("btn btn-info");
                           };
                        $.ajax(FollowOptions);
                    }
                });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Make the function a fat arrow function. It will not create its own "this".

   ```
       FollowOptions.success = ()=> {
           $(this).text("إلغاء الإنصمام");
           $(this).removeClass("btn btn-info");
           $(this).addClass("btn btn-danger");

       };
   ```
2. Bind the this to the normal function

   ```
       FollowOptions.success = function () {
           $(this).text("إلغاء الإنصمام");
           $(this).removeClass("btn btn-info");
           $(this).addClass("btn btn-danger");

       }.bind(this);
   ```

I recommend the first option as its much cleaner ('bind' creates a new function, and if you get used to using it you might have troubles when you deal with eventlisteners and such, when you would try to remove the eventlistener).

Comment: thanks it has worked ... in first option you meant that i  dont need to pass parameter  
because i dont need  use function ...and that is simplest and more performance option

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".join").click(
        function () {
            var that = this;

            if ($(that).text() == "إنضمام")
            {
                var FollowOptions = {};
                @*FollowOptions.url = "/@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name/Communities/Follow/";*@
                FollowOptions.url = "/@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name/Groups/Join/";
                FollowOptions.data = { id: $(that).attr("name") };
                FollowOptions.success = function () {
                    $(that).text("إلغاء الإنصمام");
                    $(that).removeClass("btn btn-info");
                    $(that).addClass("btn btn-danger");

                };
                $.ajax(FollowOptions);
            }
            else
            {
                var FollowOptions = {};
                FollowOptions.url = "/@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name/Groups/UnJoin/";
                FollowOptions.data = { id: $(that).attr("name") };
                FollowOptions.success = function () {
                    $(that).text("إنضمام");
                    $(that).removeClass("btn btn-danger");
                    $(that).addClass("btn btn-info");
                    };
                $.ajax(FollowOptions);
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your contribution ... but it does not work

Comment: @محمدالعاني I just edited the code, please try again to see if it works for you.